# Emmet zen coding multi cursor

Tags: emmet

How would I add `<li></li>` around multiple lines all at one time? I am using sublime, but should be same for other zen coding editors.

ex.

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

etc.

I want to select all three lines and wrap `<li></li>` on each so it becomes

```
<li>line 1</li>
<li>line 2</li>
<li>line 3</li>
```

Comment: See https://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/

Answer (score 0):

I am using web essential extension which is having zen coding plugin for visual studio 2017

if you are adding multiple list items for unordered list use,

```
ol>li*3
```

if you are adding multiple list items for ordered list use,

```
ul>li*3
```

then press tab two times contentiously.

Comment: I need to add <li> to an already existing list of data. See my question.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get your question clearly, as i know zen coding is use to write html from scratch i don't know any method for format exciting html using zen, from the scratch using cut and paste option you can use                                                                                           li{line1}+li{line2}+li{line3}                                                                                           to create the existing list from the beginning and here is a cheat list[link](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) that may be useful